# How does the Minolta AF 24 mm f2.8 compare to the Sigma AF 24mm F2.8?

Tags: lens, sony, sigma, minolta

I have an APS-C Sony A77 and I am looking for a 'walk around lens' which is wide enough to take around the city and fast enough for lower light conditions, ideally below 200€ german. With these criteria in mind I have narrowed it down to these two lenses, where the Sigma is quite a bit cheaper than the Minolta. How do they compare quality wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to look up a-mount lenses on http://www.dyxum.com/lenses/. For instance, here is information on the Minolta 24 mm: http://www.dyxum.com/lenses/Minolta-AF-24mm-F2.8_lens9.html. Each lens page has references to internal and external reviews.